Add multiple arguments to Named Navigation in Flutter
I am working on an app in which the navigation seems to be implemented in a quite complicated way. I want add another argument "userId" to this navigation. I have added the argument in the screen and the router file as shown in the code below(//ADDED by ME). I am confused how do I send this argument from the widget?. Cannot find anyone using this kind of navigation online.
Inside the widget
context.router.navigateNamed("/report/$index") //need to send another argument userId

Inside the router.dart
CupertinoRoute(
          path: '/report/:index',
          page: ReportScreenRoute.page,
        )

Inside router.gr.dart
   ReportScreenRoute.name: (routeData) {
      final pathParams = routeData.inheritedPathParams;
      final args = routeData.argsAs<ReportScreenRouteArgs>(
          orElse: () =>
              ReportScreenRouteArgs(index: pathParams.optNum('index')));
      return _i22.AutoRoutePage<dynamic>(
        routeData: routeData,
        child: _iM.ReportScreen(
          index: args.index,
          userId: args.userId, //ADDED BY ME
          key: args.key,
        ),
      );
    },


class ReportScreenRoute extends _i22.PageRouteInfo<ReportScreenRouteArgs> {
  ReportScreenRoute({
    num? index,
    String? userId, //ADDED BY ME
    _i23.Key? key,
    List<_i22.PageRouteInfo>? children,
  }) : super(
          ReportScreenRoute.name,
          args: ReportScreenRouteArgs(
            index: index,
            userId: userId,  //ADDED BY ME
            key: key,
          ),
          rawPathParams: {'index': index},
          initialChildren: children,
        );

  static const String name = 'ReportScreenRoute';
  static const _i22.PageInfo<ReportScreenRouteArgs> page =
      _i22.PageInfo<ReportScreenRouteArgs>(name);
}


class ReportScreenRouteArgs {
  const ReportScreenRouteArgs({
    this.index,
    this.userId,  //ADDED  BY ME
    this.key,
});
  final num? index; 
  final String? userId;  //ADDED BY ME
  final _i23.Key? key;
}

ReportScreen.dart
@RoutePage()
class ReportScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final num? index;
  final String? userId; //ADDED BY ME

  const ReportScreen({@PathParam('index') this.index, @PathParam('userId') this.userId, super.key});

  @override
  State<ReportScreen> createState() => _ReportScreenState();
}

Thanks in advance.

It might just be a simple problem but I am new to flutter and working in this relatively big project so it seems complicated to me.

why don't you just use context.router.push instead of named

why bro not use go_router or auto_route?

@manhtuan21 the project I am working on is already using this form of navigation for like 20-30 screens

@Nguyenfamily the project is already using this navigation on the whole

It seems like auto_route doesn't support arguments with named navigation, maybe you need to think about switching to push by PageRouteInfo

okay the way i am suggesting might not be the best , but it should work
changes i made -
removed index , added a data map - which contains your index and userId
and made changes accordingly

Inside the widget
//Make index a map
  int index = 1;
  String userId = 'user123';
  
  var data = {
    "index": index,
    "userId": userId
  };
    context.router.navigateNamed("/report/$data")

Inside the router.dart
CupertinoRoute(
      path: '/report/:data',
      page: ReportScreenRoute.page,
    )

ReportScreen.dart
@RoutePage()
class ReportScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic>? data;

  const ReportScreen({@PathParam('data') this.data,super.key});

  @override
  State<ReportScreen> createState() => _ReportScreenState();
}

Inside router.gr.dart
   ReportScreenRoute.name: (routeData) {
      final pathParams = routeData.inheritedPathParams;
      final args = routeData.argsAs<ReportScreenRouteArgs>(
          orElse: () =>
              ReportScreenRouteArgs(index: pathParams.optNum('data')));
      return _i22.AutoRoutePage<dynamic>(
        routeData: routeData,
        child: _iM.ReportScreen(
          data: args.data,
          key: args.key,
        ),
      );
    },


class ReportScreenRoute extends _i22.PageRouteInfo<ReportScreenRouteArgs> {
  ReportScreenRoute({
  Map<String, dynamic>? data,
    _i23.Key? key,
    List<_i22.PageRouteInfo>? children,
  }) : super(
          ReportScreenRoute.name,
          args: ReportScreenRouteArgs(
           data:data
            key: key,
          ),
          rawPathParams: {'data': data},
          initialChildren: children,
        );

  static const String name = 'ReportScreenRoute';
  static const _i22.PageInfo<ReportScreenRouteArgs> page =
      _i22.PageInfo<ReportScreenRouteArgs>(name);
}


class ReportScreenRouteArgs {
  const ReportScreenRouteArgs({
    this.data,
    this.key,
});
  final Map<String, dynamic>? data;
  final _i23.Key? key;
}

